# working with columns inside 'segment' element in Semantic-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grid, semantic-ui

What I need is to divide the [ui-segment](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/segment.html) into 3 columns and to show the [ui- statistic](http://semantic-ui.com/views/statistic.html)s equally divided. Below is my code to achieve that,

```
<div class="ui container">
    <div class="ui segment">
        <h3 class="ui header">World</h3>
        <div class="ui grid stackable">
            <div class="three column row">
                <div class="column">
                    <div class=" ui statistic red statistic">
                        <div class="value">
                            16%
                        </div>
                        <div class="label">
                            A
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class=" ui statistic yellow statistic">
                        <div class="value">
                            53%
                        </div>
                        <div class="label">
                            B
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class=" ui statistic green statistic">
                        <div class="value">
                            31%
                        </div>
                        <div class="label">
                            C
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this looks bad. The mobile also looks the same that the columns are out of the ui-segment.
[image]

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the interaction between Semantic UI's stackable grid and statistics.

This could be an option, but you could try the *ui statistics* grouping.

```
<div class="ui three statistics">
    <div class=" ui statistic red statistic">
        <div class="value">16%</div>
        <div class="label">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class=" ui statistic yellow statistic">
        <div class="value">53%</div>
        <div class="label">B</div>
    </div>
    ...
    ...
```

I made a sample here:
http://jsfiddle.net/4a32bbmu/

Comment: Awesome. This works. How can I center "ui-statistic" in each divide. Now it is divided correctly into 3. But the "ui-statistic" is left aligned in each divide :)

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle with the correct semantic-ui resources. I'm not sure what you mean by left aligned in each divide, is it any better with the updated jsfiddle?

Comment: Awesome. This works. I have added "class=" ui statistics red statistic" instead of class=" ui statistic red statistic". Now working as favored. Edited in the original question for future use.